# Send to each futures::sync::mpsc::Sender in array

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a dynamic collection of `futures::sync::mpsc::Sender`, and I would like to send a message to each of them for every incoming connection.

I have it working with `UnboundedSender`, because I can just do that (see below) but `Sender` consumes itself, so I need to remove and reinsert it into the `Vec` after sending. How can I do this? If the `Sender` blocks, it should not send more messages, but instead switch to handling the incoming connections on the receiver.

The `UnboundedSender` implementation is below, my failed attempt at doing it otherwise is commented out inline (just replace the preceeding line with the commented out one).

## UnboundedSender (works)

```
extern crate tokio;
use tokio::runtime::current_thread;

extern crate futures;
use futures::{stream, Stream, Sink};
use futures::sync::mpsc;

fn main() {
    let values = vec![1 as i8, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, -1];
    let mut senders = Vec::<mpsc::UnboundedSender<i8>>::new();
    let stream = stream::iter_ok::<_, ()>(values)
        .for_each(|v| {
            match v {
                0 => {
                    println!("Adding channel");
                    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::unbounded();
                    senders.push(sender);
                    current_thread::spawn(receiver.for_each(|v| {
                        println!("Received {}", v);
                        Ok(())
                    }))

                },
                -1 => {
                    println!("Closing channels");
                    senders.clear();
                },
                x => {
                    for sender in senders.iter() {
                        println!("Sending {}", x);
                        sender.unbounded_send(x).unwrap();
                    }
                },
            }
            Ok(())
        });

    current_thread::block_on_all(stream)
        .expect("Failed to run stream");
    println!("Done!");
}
```

## Sender (doesn't work)

```
extern crate tokio;
use tokio::runtime::current_thread;

extern crate futures;
use futures::{stream, Stream, Sink};
use futures::sync::mpsc;

fn main() {
    let values = vec![1 as i8, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, -1];
    let mut senders = Vec::<mpsc::Sender<i8>>::new();
    let stream = stream::iter_ok::<_, ()>(values)
        .for_each(|v| {
            match v {
                0 => {
                    println!("Adding channel");
                    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel(1);
                    senders.push(sender);
                    current_thread::spawn(receiver.for_each(|v| {
                        println!("Received {}", v);
                        Ok(())
                    }))

                },
                -1 => {
                    println!("Closing channels");
                    senders.clear();
                },
                x => {
                    for sender in senders.iter() {
                        println!("Sending {}", x);
                        sender.send(x);
                        //^error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
                    }
                },
            }
            Ok(())
        });

    current_thread::block_on_all(stream)
        .expect("Failed to run stream");
    println!("Done!");
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the sourcecode that provokes the error? I'm not sure what to do to reproduce your error

Comment: Btw, you are propably looking for `sender.clone().send(x)`

Comment: See edits for example. I'm not sure `sender.clone().send(x)` is what I want, as I don't want to add capacity to my channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've worked it out - the trick is to pass `senders` in and keep passing it down the chain of futures. This doesn't handle the `-1` to clear senders but the extension is straightforward.

```
extern crate tokio;
use tokio::runtime::current_thread;

extern crate futures;
use futures::{stream, Stream, Sink, Future, IntoFuture};
use futures::sync::mpsc;
use futures::future::Either;

fn main() {
    let values = vec![0, 1, 0, 2, 3];
    let stream = stream::iter_ok::<Vec<i8>, mpsc::SendError<i8>>(values)
        .fold(Vec::new(), |mut senders, v| {
            match v {
                0 => {
                    println!("Adding channel");
                    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel(0);
                    senders.push(sender);
                    let idx = senders.len();
                    current_thread::spawn(receiver.for_each(move |v| {
                        println!("Received {} in channel {}", v, idx);
                        Ok(())
                    }));
                    Either::A(Ok(senders).into_future())
                },
                value => {
                    println!("Sending {}...", value);
                    Either::B(stream::iter_ok(senders).and_then(move |tx| {
                        tx.send(value)
                    }).collect().map(move |senders| {
                        println!("Sent {}.", value);
                        senders
                    }))
                },
            }
        }).map(drop);

    current_thread::block_on_all(stream)
        .expect("Failed to run stream");
    println!("Done!");
}
```

This outputs:

```
Adding channel
Sending 1...
Received 1 in channel 1
Sent 1.
Adding channel
Sending 2...
Received 2 in channel 1
Received 2 in channel 2
Sent 2.
Sending 3...
Received 3 in channel 1
Received 3 in channel 2
Sent 3.
Done!
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, You have two main problems, `send()` take the ownership of `Sender` so you have to clone somewhere if you want reuse it later and also it returns a future that you have to process somehow.

There are different ways to fix these problems, here one:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio;

use futures::sync::mpsc;
use futures::Future;
use futures::{stream, Sink, Stream};

fn main() {
    let values = vec![1i8, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, -1]; // remove cast syntax
    let mut senders = vec![]; // remove annotations
    let stream = stream::iter_ok(values).for_each(move |v| { // move senders
        match v {
            0 => {
                println!("Adding channel");
                let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel(1);
                senders.push(sender);
                tokio::spawn(receiver.for_each(|v| {
                    println!("Received {}", v);
                    Ok(())
                }));
            }
            -1 => {
                println!("Closing channels");
                senders.clear();
            }
            x => {
                for sender in senders.iter() {
                    let send = sender
                        .clone() // clone sender
                        .send(x)
                        .map(move |_| println!("Sending {}", x))
                        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("error = {:?}", e));
                    tokio::spawn(send); // spawn the task
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    });

    tokio::run(stream);
    println!("Done!");
}
```

Comment: This does work, however I'd like to avoid cloning the sender if possible - if the channel is full, the event loop should block and switch to processing the already sent messages. With this code, I get all the `Adding channel` and `Sending _`, and then all the `Receiving _` printed, they should be interleaved.

Comment: @kai Unfortunately this is beyond my knowledge, also you are not allowed to block in a `for_each()` of a stream.

Comment: OK, I'll keep at it for a few more days and accept this answer if I can't figure anything out. Thanks!